# GWT RPC. When onSuccess() method invokes?

Tags: java, gwt

If  RPC method return `Void`, then will it call `onSuccess()` method? Or I must to return some value to cause RPC to call `onSuccess()` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If asynchronous request finishes successfully regardless its return value `onSuccess()` method will be called. So, you don't have to return the object which is not necessary.

> void onSuccess(T result) Called when an asynchronous call completes
>   successfully. [From documentation](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/AsyncCallback.html)

Answer (score 3):

If your server side method returns an object, the code would look like:

```
rpcService.doSomething(ArgumentToServerSide, new AsyncCallback<ReturnType>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ReturnType result) {
                    // DO what you expect on Success 
                    }
                    @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                    // DO what is expected on failure
                    }
```

In case server side method does not return anything i.e. return type is `void` then your code would look like:

```
rpcService.doSomething(ArgumentToServerSide, new AsyncCallback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void result) {
                    // DO what you expect on Success 
                    }
                    @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                    // DO what is expected on failure
                    }
```

Did you notice that `onSuccess` method gets a object of Type `Void`, which is a placeholder for keyword void (Check documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html)

So essentially if your method returns a certain type, `onSuccess` and `onFailure` will return that type, else it will return type `Void`
Hope this helps.